# Homebrew issues since Mavericks update

Tags: homebrew, thrift, osx-mavericks

I upgraded to Mavericks the week before last and started experiencing problems with homebrew ever since. 'brew doctor' reports no issues but I'm currently trying to install Apache Thrift and it's failing. Any suggestions?

```
brew install thrift
==> Installing thrift dependency: boost
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/boost-1.54.0.mavericks.bottle.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring boost-1.54.0.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Caveats

The Boost bottle's module will not import into a Homebrew-installed Python.
If you use the Boost Python module then please:
  brew install boost --build-from-source
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0: 9865 files, 588M
==> Installing thrift
==> Downloading http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi?path=thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz
==> Best Mirror http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/www.apache.org/dist/thrift/0.9.0/thrift-0.9.0.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file lib/cpp/src/thrift/transport/TSocket.h
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.9.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/thrift/0.9.0/lib
==> make
make[4]: *** [ThreadManager.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to follow this Jira ticket. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2229

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a [pull request](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23315) for homebrew to fix this issue.  A temporary work around could be to change the compiler you're using, but I'd recommend just waiting for the patch to be rolled out.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. You should try

```
brew update
```

And then continue with your install